# How to get photos in certain radius from location in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I have an location coordinates. I have a radius (5 km, for example) around this location. How to get google maps photos (images, description/comments for photo, coordinates)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use google maps api (notice there's a new google maps v2 for android you can download [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

As for getting specific coordinate data, you should consider google places api.
you can use [this](http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/) great detailed tutorial, and a tutorial which I believe most fits your needs, combining the two: [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/).  There are queries for photos, reviews, etc.  Note that this is a separate API from Google Maps.

Comment: HaHa =) we answered the same thing at the same time